# Cookie redirection on splash pages

Tags: php, cookies

Here's whats happening on our third party's end:

- GEO IP tracking drives traffic to .com; .be; .nl or .fr
- There is Cookie in place so that a customer who has gone to a site before, will be re-directed there without hitting the GEO IP loop again. (we pay per hit)

Thus, if a customer was routed to .fr or .nl in the past, they will be routed back to that page, regardless if they chose the .be or .com site afterward.

At this point, we would like our environment to put a cookie on the splash pages so that:

- If a customer has been to our-site.nl or our-site.fr and they have chosen .be; they will be routed directly to .be.
- If a customer has been to our-site.nl or our-site.fr and they chose .com; they will be routed directly to .com

How can I go about achieving the above?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved pretty simple.
Suppose your user is on **our-site.fr** and wants to **our-site.be**

You could link to **our-site.be** (e.g. with flags of the contries) on **our-site.fr** like that:

```
<a href="http://our-site.be/?setcountry=be"><img src='flag_be.png'></a>
```

Now you can access the $_GET-array on **our-site.be** to check if the user has set the country via the flags/dropdown/whatever:

```
if(isset($_GET['setcountry'])){
   //The cookie name and value should correspond Geo ip cookie
   setcookie("languageselect", $_GET['setcountry'], time()+3600*24*30); 
}
```

So you just overwrite the cookie of the geo ip location.